# Changing Colors on Markers

Tags: c#, gmap.net

I am trying to import a file with a list of latitude and longitude coordinates.  In Visual C#, and using GMAP.NET, a marker is placed for every coordinate pair.  I want multiple files to be able to be uploaded, and for the user to be able to select the color of the marker for that specific file. I have a combobox with a few options included, however when I try to set the color of the marker to the text in the textbox, it can't "implicitly convert type string to GMarkerGoogleType". Is there a way to make this conversion?

Here is the relevant code:

```
private void btn_KMLFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog4.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string filename = openFileDialog4.FileName;
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename);
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                GMarkerGoogleType MarkerColor = cbo_MarkerType.Text;  //How can I convert this string to a GMarkerGoogleType?
                string[] Data_Array = line.Split(',');
                Double londecimal = Convert.ToDouble(Data_Array[0]);
                Double latdecimal = Convert.ToDouble(Data_Array[1]);
                var marker3 = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(latdecimal, londecimal), MarkerColor);
                marker3.IsVisible = true;
                gMapOverlay.Markers.Add(marker3);

                gmap.Update();


            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT: This question is not a duplicate, the question can be rephrased as what type is a GMarkerGoogleType?

Comment: Have a look at the enum's definition in the [source code](https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GMap.NET.WindowsForms/GMap.NET.WindowsForms/Markers/GMarkerGoogle.cs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GMarkerGoogleType` is an `enum`, so you're basically asking for a conversion from `string` to `GMarkerGoogleType`:

```
GMarkerGoogleType MarkerColor = (GMarkerGoogleType)Enum.Parse(typeof(GMarkerGoogleType), cbo_MarkerType.Text, true);
```

Comment: when I try this I get the following error:  Must specify valid information for parsing in the string.  How do I correct this? EDIT: Figured it out, it was in another part of the code, Thanks for the help!